# How to calculate the memory occupied by caffeine cache

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory, caffeine

We have a requirement to calculate the total memory occupied for the cached objects in spring boot application. We are using caffeine cache implementation.

Any pointer we can get the details about memory uses ?

Comment: Calculating memory usage in Java is extraordinarily hard, and that has nothing to do with Caffeine.

Comment: It's typically not very useful, but can be estimated with [JAMM](https://github.com/jbellis/jamm).